# Modal SwiftUI text is all caps?

Tags: ios, swiftui

In a SwiftUI modal view the text is ALL CAPS for some reason until one interacts with it then all the text snaps to their desired state (normal case). What can be the cause of this behaviour?

The ListIngredientHeader is simply a header in a Section that is in a Form. This view is then inside a NavigationView at the very top of the view hierarchy..

```
// NOTE: Presents the modal view below
struct ListIngredientHeader: View {
    @Binding var ingredients: [MeasuredIngredient]
    @State var showIngredientsModal: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(uiImage: "".image()).resizable().frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            Text("Ingredients").font(.headline)
            Spacer()
            Button {
                self.showIngredientsModal = true
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle").resizable().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 25, height: 25)
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showIngredientsModal) {
                ModalIngredientView(ingredients: $ingredients)
            }
        }
    }
}


// MARK: Modal views
struct ModalIngredientView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var ingredients: [MeasuredIngredient]
    @State private var ingredientString: String = ""
    @State private var measurementSelection = FoodUnit.deciliters
    @State private var measurementQuantity: String = ""
    @State private var measurementType: MeasurementType = .volume
    @State private var quantityNotApplicable: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                HStack {
                    Text("Name")
                    TextField("Potato", text: $ingredientString)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Quantity").foregroundColor(quantityNotApplicable ? .gray : .primary)
                    TextField(quantityNotApplicable ? "-" : "100", text: $measurementQuantity).keyboardType(.numberPad).disabled(quantityNotApplicable)
                    Divider()
                    Toggle("N.A", isOn: $quantityNotApplicable)
                }
                
                Picker("Measurement", selection: $measurementSelection) {
                    ForEach(FoodUnit.allCases) {
                        Text("\($0.rawValue)").tag($0)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("New Ingredient")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Prior to touch]

[image: After touching]

Comment: Would you show code to reproduce this?

Comment: I have added code and more information, please reopen the question people

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been awhile since you posted the question... I just hit this issue and found a solution, so hopefully that helps you or someone else.

`Section` (from within a `Form` or `List`) uses `textCase(.uppercase)` by default. If you display a sheet from within the `Section`'s label view, the sheet's content view "inherits" the `.uppercase` setting and displays **all** text in `.uppercase`.
I would consider this a bug in SwiftUI.

The solution for me was to add `textCase(.none)` to the sheet's content, for example:

```swift
.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
   // on dismiss
} content: {
   SheetContentView()
       .textCase(.none) // <-- fixes issues with caps
}
```

If you're displaying a `Form` or a `List` with `Section` **within** the sheet's content view, those will correctly show in caps, you don't need to do anything.